# Unable to build a mariaDB base in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, mariadb, dockerfile

I am currently blocked, I want to build a data base when I build a Dockerfile. But I got an error and i don't understand why. Thanks for your help.

Here my Dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:latest

WORKDIR /sql-files

ADD sql/ /sql-files/

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD test123
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE testDB
ENV MYSQL_USER toto
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD test123

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install vim && chmod +x insertDB.sh && sh insertDB.sh

EXPOSE 3306
```

Here my insertDB.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
sleep 5
mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE < test.sql
```

and finaly my test.sql script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES
('Toto'),
('Jack'),
('Titi');
```

So when i execute my docker file with the command `docker build -t maria .` I get this error:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
171112 18:12:53 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
171112 18:12:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'testDB'
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -y install vim && chmod +x insertDB.sh && sh insertDB.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What am i missed ?

Comment: what happens when you change the user name and password to of ROOT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [mariadb image from dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) it's simpler than what you tried.

As explained in "Initializing a fresh instance section":

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order.

So it's enough you add just `test.sql` script to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Then your Dockerfile must run mysqld as command.

So, I would leave only `test.sql` in local `sql` subdirectory and I would use this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mariadb:latest

ADD sql/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD test123
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE testDB
ENV MYSQL_USER toto
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD test123

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install vim

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Then build your image

```
docker build -t maria .
```

and run the container (may be useful to map port)

```
docker run --name mariadb -ti -d -p 3306:3306 maria
```

It creates `testDB` and user `toto`, as you correctly defined using the environment variables in Dockerfiles (remind that you can override them as `-e` parameters in the `docker run`).

Comment: Thank you! I used your example but I removed "CMD ["mysqld"]" and it worked. CMD["mysqld"] caused the following error: mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing two things:

1. You have to create the database using `CREATE DATABASE testDB` command.
2. You have to create the user using `CREATE USER 'toto'` command.

You have to do this before you run `test.sql` script. The docker image you are using comes completely empty - it does not know about the database or user you are trying to use there.

If you do the above steps and still get `permission denied`, you should also include a `GRANT` statement which will give `toto` the necessary permissions on the database `testDB`. Check MariaDB documentation for details.

Comment: It's already done. When I set my environment variables, the user `toto` is created and the database too. I also try to create it manually, but i still have the same error :(.